# In what situation are listener parameters mandatory?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, lambda, listener

I wrote two different listeners for my button:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener{myOnClick()}
myButton.setOnKeyListener{myOnKeyListener()}
```

The first one is OK for the compiler. But second one gives an error. It says **Expected 3 parameters of types View!, Int, KeyEvent!**

Considering that these are the listeners in the View class:

```
public interface OnClickListener {
     void onClick(View v);
}

public interface OnKeyListener {
     boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
}
```

Any idea about why is asking me for the parameters in one situation but not in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `OnClickListener.onClick` takes only one parameter but `OnKeyListener.onKey` takes three. In Kotlin you don't need to specify single lambda's parameter and you can access it with the implicit name `it`. But when lambda expects more parameters you cannot access them with `it` anymore. That's why you have to explicitly give them names.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much Andrei ;)